# If TTS not supporting Kannada Language, how to play the text in Kannada

Tags: java, android, localization

When I am set locale in "kn" and reading text also in Kannada so my TTS not working.
Please check below.

```
t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {

            t1.setLanguage(new Locale("kn"));
        }
    }
});


b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String toSpeak = "ಹಲೋ ಹೇಗಿದ್ದೀರಿ";
        t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
});
```

Comment: Any solution for this.

Comment: What is "not working"? You need to be specific about what is happening here. Also, 20 minutes is a bit of a short amount of time to be getting impatient that nobody has answered. See here for how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello urbane spaceman thanks for your advice, Now thats specification is ok aur need to some more info, Now plz give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is not available right now.
Please check https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

you can check in programmatically using

```
Locale myLocale = new Locale("kn");
if( TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE == t1.isLanguageAvailable(myLocale){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But its always going in else block means not equal  (==) to locale lang.

Comment: this is because kn is not yet supported

Comment: Okay so how we can do TTS in kannad(kn).

Comment: you've to use commercial, not standard TextToSpeech